Control Simulation Node bake settings in Python
I am trying to access/control these properties of Simulation node in Python (custom frame start, end):

But, seems like they are not directly exposed to Python. 
Is it somehow possible to control them or expose in UI outside of Node editor?
Thanks!

import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C

obj = C.object
# quick and dirty way to access the modifier, name-based is not foolproof
# but works for this example
mod = obj.modifiers['Nodes']

# the attributes you're looking for are in the 
# NodesModifierBake sub-object of the modifier itself
bake = mod.bakes[0]
bake.frame_start = 10
bake.frame_end = 50 

I was able to find this out by going here:

Which takes you to this page.

From this page you can poke around and see near the bottom that it seems like this is a sub-object of the NodesModifier object, in it's bakes attribute.


Wow! Thank you very much!!
